# Integrate rich text editor in Nativescript-Angular2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor, nativescript

I want to integrate a Rich text editor like [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) In my Nativescript-Angular2 mobile app. So I tried to add [ng2-ckeditor-codemirror](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor-codemirror) in my app. The app is building fine but while launching the app it is giving error like the following

> JS: EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:1:2 caused by: CKEDITOR is not defined
>   JS: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: CKEDITOR is not defined
>   JS: ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>   JS: ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined
>   JS:     at CKEditorComponent.ckeditorInit (/data/data/org.nativescript.MyCkEditor/files/app/tns_modules/ng2-ckeditor/lib/ckeditor.component.js:71:14)
>   JS:     at CKEditorComponent.ngAfterViewInit (/data/data/org.nativescript.MyCkEditor/files/app/tns_modules/ng2-ckeditor/lib/ckeditor.component.js:52:14)
>   JS:     at DebugAppView.View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/component.ngfactory.js:81:76)
>   JS:     at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.MyCkEditor/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12587:18)
>   JS:     at DebugAppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.MyCkEditor/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12734:48)
>   JS:     at DebugAppView.AppView.internalDetectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.MyCkEditor/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12572:22)
>   JS:     at DebugAppView.View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)
>   JS:     at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.MyCkEditor/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12587:18)
>   JS:     at DebugAppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.MyCkEditor/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12734:48)
>   JS:     at ViewRef_.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.MyCkEditor/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9814:24)
>   JS: ERROR CONTEXT:
>   JS: [object Object]
>   JS: ns-renderer: ERROR BOOTSTRAPPING ANGULAR
>   JS: ns-renderer: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:1:2 caused by: CKEDITOR is not defined

Please help me out to solve this issue, else suggest me a rich text editor which will work With Nativescript-Angular2 stack.

Thanks

Comment: update with the steps you tried in your post

Comment: Thanks @Aravind For your response

Here are the Steps from project creation.

1. tns create <projectname> --ng
2. cd <projectname>
3.  Then I followed the instruction of [This plugin](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor).
4. tns build android
5. On launching of the app, it gave the above stated error.

Comment: The CKEditor is distributed in the form of a javascript file, so you would first need to acquire a license from their site. the ng2-ckeditor package expects that you reference the ckeditor script one way or another. Also I noticed that the CKEditor is pure html, which is unlikely to work in the context of NativeScript.

Comment: May be this is the reason @pkanev.